# Count of MFA option used by users in ADB2C custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

We have implemented adb2c custom polices for providing options to user to select preferred method for MFA i.e either by Phone/SMS or Email.

Is there a way to find the analytics that how much time users are using either of the method.
Need this to identify if we really need to provide two options going forward or can remove one of them.
Appreciate any help on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add [extra data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#collect-more-data) to App Insights based on MFA selection.

You can then query the data and analyse the results.

Comment: Thank you , this worked for me. just a quick question - Is there a way to know if user has used SMS or Call option when they selected phone for MFA?

Comment: If it sets a claim when the user selects the method, you could use that.